# Соединение строк в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Во второй части кода беру кук, беру id фото из одной таблицы , получаю значение  `Ppage` из другой таблицы с помощью кука, складываю строки  `$DoPpage` и  `$id` и помещаю это значение в  `Ppage`.Не понимаю в чём ошибка.

```
<?php
    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register');
    $img_type = substr($_FILES['img']['type'], 0, 5);
    $img_size = 2*1024*1024;
    if(!empty($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']) and $img_type === 'image' and $_FILES['img']['size'] <= $img_size){ 
    $img = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']));
    $txt = filter_var(trim($_POST ['txt']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if(mb_strlen($txt) < 0 || mb_strlen($txt) > 1000) {
        echo "Недопустимая длина описания";
        exit();
    }
```

```
$mysql->query("INSERT INTO `photo` (`text`, `img`) VALUES ( '$txt', '$img')");
$cook = $_COOKIE['login'];
$id = $mysql->query("SELECT `id` FROM `photo` WHERE `img` = '$img' ");
$DoPpage = $mysql->query("SELECT `Ppage` FROM `users` WHERE `login` = '$cook'");
$sym = strval($DoPpage) . strval($id);
$mysql->query("UPDATE `users` SET `Ppage` = '$sym' WHERE `login` = '$cook'");
}

$mysql->close();

header('Location: /Akk-red.php');
```

Comment: да, так в чем ошибка - что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что вы неправильно извлекаете данные из базы MySQL
Исползайте функцию  [mysqli_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) или [mysqli_fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Comment: Как именно их использовать